# UICollectionViewFlowLayout subclass crashes accessing array beyond bounds while scrolling and reloading

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a UICollectionView that uses a custom subclass of UICollectionViewFlowLayout to make the section headers stick to the top of the screen while scrolling just like UITableView's plain style. My code is based on this approach:

http://blog.radi.ws/post/32905838158/sticky-headers-for-uicollectionview-using

In addition, the collection view is set up to load more results when the user scrolls to the bottom. That is, when the user gets to the bottom of the collection view, a web request loads more data and then reloads the collection view, i.e. calling reloadData.

It seems to work well except I've been getting a few crash reports from beta testers via TestFlight running iOS 7 and 7.1 who say that the following happens occasionally when they scroll down to the bottom (i.e. triggering more results to load) quickly:

```
*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 28 beyond bounds [0 .. 16]
PRIMARY THREAD THREAD 0

__exceptionPreprocess
objc_exception_throw
-[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]
-[UICollectionViewFlowLayout(Internal) _frameForItemAtSection:andRow:usingData:]
-[UICollectionViewFlowLayout layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:usingData:]
-[UICollectionViewFlowLayout layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:]
-[MyCustomCollectionViewFlowLayout layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:]
-[MyCustomCollectionViewFlowLayout layoutAttributesForSupplementaryViewOfKind:atIndexPath:]
-[MyCustomCollectionViewFlowLayout layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:]
-[UICollectionViewData validateLayoutInRect:]_block_invoke
-[UICollectionViewData validateLayoutInRect:]
-[UICollectionView layoutSubviews]
-[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:]
-[CALayer layoutSublayers]
```

It seems as though when my custom flow layout code calls `[self.collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:someSection]` to get the layout attributes of a section's last item, that call returns based on the newly-loaded data (e.g. in this case that a section now has 29 items) but the internals of the default flow layout are still using some kind of cached data (e.g. in this case that the section only has 17 items). Unfortunately, I can't reproduce the crash myself and even the beta testers who have experienced it can't reproduce it consistently.

Any ideas what's going on there?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Edit 2**, as per 2nd BenRB's comment.

When  dataSource gets updated and you call reloadData, this latter really invalidates everything in the collection view. 
However the logic and the **exact sequence** of the initiated refresh process happens inside the default flow layout and is hidden from us.

In particular, the default flow layout has its own private `_prepareLayout` (exactly, with underscore) method, which is independent from the `prepareLayout` and its overloads provided by the subclasses.

`prepareLayout`'s (without underscore) default implementation of the base flow layout class does nothing, by the way.

During the refresh process the default flow layout gives its subclass a chance to provide more information (e.g. additional layoutAttributes) through  `layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:` and `layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:` "callbacks". To guarantee  the consistency between base class' data and respective indexPath / layoutAttributes array, calls to corresponding "super"  should only happen inside these respective methods:

- `[super layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:]` only inside the
  overloaded `[layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:]`
- `[super layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:]` only inside the overloaded `[layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:]`,

No cross-calls between these methods should happen, at least with indexPaths not supplied by their corresponding "super" methods, because **we don't know exactly what happens inside**.

I was fighting with my collection view for a long time and ended with the only **working sequence finally:**

1. Prepare add'l layout data by directly accessing the dataSource (without mediation of collection view's numberOfItemsInSection:), and store that data inside the subclass' object, e.g. in a dictionary property, using indexPath as a key.  I am doing this in the overloaded `[prepareLayout]`.
2. Supply the stored layout data to the base class when it requests this information through callbacks:

// layoutAttributesForElementsInRect

```
- (NSArray *)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect {

//calls super to get the array of layoutAttributes initialised by the base class
**NSArray *array = [super layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:rect];**

for(MyLayoutAttributes *la in array)

    if(la.representedElementCategory == UICollectionElementCategoryCell ){
       NSIndexPath indexPath =  la.indexPath //only this indexPath can be used during the call to layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:!!! 
       //extracts custom layout data from a layouts dictionary
       MyLayoutAttributes *cellLayout = layouts[la.indexPath];  
       //sets additional properties
        la.this = cellLayout.this
        la.that = cellLayout.that
        ...
    }
   ....
return array;
}
```

//layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:

```
- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  MyLayoutAttributes *la = (MyLayoutAttributes *)[super layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath ];

    if(la.representedElementCategory == UICollectionElementCategoryCell ){
        NSIndexPath indexPath =  la.indexPath //only this indexPath can be used during the call !!! 
       //extracts custom layout data from a layouts dictionary using indexPath as a key
       MyLayoutAttributes *cellLayout = layouts[la.indexPath];  
       //sets additional properties
        la.this = cellLayout.this
        la.that = cellLayout.that
    }
return la;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Vladimir. I'm actually not implementing prepareLayout. I'm mainly implementing layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:. For consistency I also implement layoutAttributesForSupplementaryViewOfKind:atIndexPath: and layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:. My CV data source is just an array. The sequence is essentially: user scrolls to bottom, web request returns array, array is added to existing array, I call reloadData, framework calls layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:, I call numberOfItemsInSection: getting the new data and [super layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:] crashes due to old data.

Comment: OK. So you're thinking the default flow layout is contacting the CV data source to get the section counts in prepareLayout, then I'm changing the array, calling reloadData and then the framework calls layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:? I.e. prepareLayout doesn't happen right before layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:? So to keep consistent with the internals of the default flow layout, calls to CV data source must happen in prepareLayout and are later used in layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:? UICollectionViewLayoutInvalidationContext docs make it sound like reloadData invalidates everything.

Comment: The call of reloadData really invalidates everything in CV. However the logic of the initiated refresh process happens inside the default flow layout and is hidden from us. We don't know at what moment of time the default flow layout constructs its internal arrays. Therefore, we should not use these internal structures unless we are 100% sure that they are in actual state. By calling `layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:` with indexPath(s) received not from the default flow layout, but from external source, you risk to request inconsistent or non-existing data. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: I rewrote my code to get around this. Existing: Get section info from data source to create index path for section's last item, pass that to layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath: to get default position to calculate furthest down header can be before being pushed off top of screen by next section. New: Use return from default layoutAttributesForElementsInRect: to get furthest down onscreen item in section. Doesn't always give true last element of section since it might be offscreen but in that case header won't need to be down that far since it'll be stuck to screen's top or in default position.

Comment: The thing I don't like about this workaround is that I can't implement layoutAttributesForSupplementaryViewOfKind:atIndexPath: to return an accurate value since it would need to access the data source and get default layout attributes for items. However in my usage, that method doesn't seem to be called. The docs say to implement it though. And I still feel like there must be a way to consult the data source and know that the default flow layout doesn't have an out of date cache. For now I'll accept, go with this and report back if I come up with something better or this turns out to not work.

Answer (score 4):

I'm now getting a crash that looks similar, i.e. where the layout is out of sync with the data source. This one I can reproduce and I believe I've found the cause. Since it is similar, I'm wondering if it is the same cause as my original crash/question. The error is:

> UICollectionView recieved [sic] layout attributes for a cell with an index path that does not exist

My `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` subclass implements `shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange:` (so that I can position section headers at the top of the viewable bounds as the user scrolls). If a bounds change occurs and that method returns `YES`, the system requests a light-weight layout invalidation, i.e. all the properties on the invalidation context that is passed to the layout are `NO`: `invalidateEverything`, `invalidateDataSourceCounts`, `invalidateFlowLayoutAttributes` and `invalidateFlowLayoutDelegateMetrics`. If `reloadData` is then called afterwards (presumably before the layout has been reprocessed) then the system will not automatically call `invalidateLayout`, i.e. it will not trigger a heavy-weight invalidation context where all those properties are `YES`. So when that happens the layout apparently does not update its internal cache of section/item counts and such, which the leads to the layout being out of sync with the data source and a crash.

So for the particular situation I just ran into, I was able to work around it by simply calling `invalidateLayout` myself after calling `reloadData`. I'm not sure if this is the same situation as my original question/crash but it sure sounds like it.

Comment: I fix it. 'shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange' reture NO before 'reloadData'

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem. and I fixed it.

```
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
UICollectionView *collectionView = self.collectionView;
[UIView performWithoutAnimation:^{
    [collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
        collectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        __strong typeof(self) strongSelf = weakSelf;
        if (strongSelf){
            [strongSelf reloadThumbData];
        }
    }];
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue although in my case with a custom layout. 
My solution was to call:

- insertItems
- deleteItems
- updateItems

on the collectionView as appropriate to ensure that dataSource and layout are aware of the same number of items.

My layout is based on the data returned from:

```
super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect)
```

which was not returning the expected number of items that the dataSource indicated.

The documentation for insertItems seems to corroborate this:

```
Call this method to insert one or more new items into the collection 
view. You might do this when your data source object receives data for 
new items or in response to user interactions with the collection view. 
The collection view gets the layout information for the new cells as 
part of calling this method.
```