# UICollectionView sticky header in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout, tvos

I'm trying to create a sticky supplementary header, which stays on top all the time and won't response to scrolling events. The solutions I found so far still react on bounch scrolling and are fixed using a custom flowLayout, which will probably be the fix for mine issue as well.

The reason I want it this way is that the header is used on other places and should be reusable. I'm hoping this could be solved this way and I don't have to create a separated view.

As I'm doing this in Swift, it would be great to have an example in Swift.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**The final solution I found:**

Using this custom flow layout it was possible to fix this sticky header:

```
class StickyHeaderCollectionViewFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

    override func layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect: CGRect) -> [AnyObject]? {

        var superAttributes: [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? = super.layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect) as? [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]

        if superAttributes == nil {
            // If superAttributes couldn't cast, return
            return super.layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect)
        }

        let contentOffset = collectionView!.contentOffset
        var missingSections = NSMutableIndexSet()

        for layoutAttributes in superAttributes! {
            if (layoutAttributes.representedElementCategory == .Cell) {
                if let indexPath = layoutAttributes.indexPath {
                    missingSections.addIndex(layoutAttributes.indexPath.section)
                }
            }
        }

        for layoutAttributes in superAttributes! {
            if let representedElementKind = layoutAttributes.representedElementKind {
                if representedElementKind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader {
                    if let indexPath = layoutAttributes.indexPath {
                        missingSections.removeIndex(indexPath.section)
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        missingSections.enumerateIndexesUsingBlock { idx, stop in
            let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forItem: 0, inSection: idx)
            if let layoutAttributes = self.layoutAttributesForSupplementaryViewOfKind(UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, atIndexPath: indexPath) {
                superAttributes!.append(layoutAttributes)
            }
        }

        for layoutAttributes in superAttributes! {
            if let representedElementKind = layoutAttributes.representedElementKind {
                if representedElementKind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader {
                    let section = layoutAttributes.indexPath!.section
                    let numberOfItemsInSection = collectionView!.numberOfItemsInSection(section)

                    let firstCellIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forItem: 0, inSection: section)!
                    let lastCellIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forItem: max(0, (numberOfItemsInSection - 1)), inSection: section)!


                    let (firstCellAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes, lastCellAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes) = {
                        if (self.collectionView!.numberOfItemsInSection(section) > 0) {
                            return (
                                self.layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath(firstCellIndexPath),
                                self.layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath(lastCellIndexPath))
                        } else {
                            return (
                                self.layoutAttributesForSupplementaryViewOfKind(UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, atIndexPath: firstCellIndexPath),
                                self.layoutAttributesForSupplementaryViewOfKind(UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter, atIndexPath: lastCellIndexPath))
                        }
                        }()

                    let headerHeight = CGRectGetHeight(layoutAttributes.frame)
                    var origin = layoutAttributes.frame.origin

                    origin.y = min(contentOffset.y, (CGRectGetMaxY(lastCellAttributes.frame) - headerHeight))
                    // Uncomment this line for normal behaviour:
                    // origin.y = min(max(contentOffset.y, (CGRectGetMinY(firstCellAttributes.frame) - headerHeight)), (CGRectGetMaxY(lastCellAttributes.frame) - headerHeight))

                    layoutAttributes.zIndex = 1024
                    layoutAttributes.frame = CGRect(origin: origin, size: layoutAttributes.frame.size)
                }
            }
        }

        return superAttributes
    }

    override func shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange(newBounds: CGRect) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

}
```

To create a layout where the headers are sticky like traditional, change this line:

```
origin.y = min(contentOffset.y, (CGRectGetMaxY(lastCellAttrs.frame) - headerHeight))
```

to this line:

```
origin.y = min(max(contentOffset.y, (CGRectGetMinY(firstCellAttrs.frame) - headerHeight)), (CGRectGetMaxY(lastCellAttrs.frame) - headerHeight))
```

Hoping this is useful for others!

**Update**

Updated to fix a crash (thanks to Robert Atkins!) and some updates to Swift 1.2

**tvOS & iOS 9**

tvOS and iOS 9 introduced the property `sectionHeadersPinToVisibleBounds` which can be used

Comment: I'm getting an EXC_ARITHMETIC crash on the `firstCellAttrs = ...` line, possibly something related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24616797/uicollectionviewflowlayout-subclass-crashes-accessing-array-beyond-bounds-while ?

Comment: Apparently this does not work for me: Xcode 6.1.1 and iOS 8 :-( Any ideas?  Could you do a retest please? The header should stick to the top like in https://github.com/jamztang/CSStickyHeaderFlowLayout right?

Comment: Doesn't work for me crashes here
`self.layoutAttributesForSupplementaryViewOfKind(UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter, atIndexPath: lastCellIndexPath))`

Comment: @NickWargnier make sure you have at least one cell in your section. A fix needs to be added for that in the code above

Comment: > sectionHeadersPinToVisibleBounds

You save my day, dude! Thanks!
All other solutions are DRASTICALLY slow.

Answer (score 92):

Simplest solution for iOS 9 + as it doesn't need of writing subclass of UICollectionViewFlowLayout.

In viewDidLoad of viewController with collectionView use following code:

```
let layout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout // casting is required because UICollectionViewLayout doesn't offer header pin. Its feature of UICollectionViewFlowLayout
layout?.sectionHeadersPinToVisibleBounds = true
```

It is hinted by @Antoine also.

Comment: This method works, but I wonder why the sectionheader is pushed up when it met by footer

Comment: This is awesome! Best solution.

Comment: Definitely most straight forward and easily working solution.

Comment: Now that it's alright to drop iOS 8, this answer is AWESOME :D

Comment: This is awesome!

Comment: if subclassing UICollectionView and  UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout  `(collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout)?.sectionHeadersPinToVisibleBounds = true`

Answer (score 3):

works for me with swift 2.0

```
override func layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {

    var superAttributes:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray(array: super.layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect)!) as NSMutableArray

    let contentOffset = collectionView!.contentOffset
    var missingSections = NSMutableIndexSet()

    for layoutAttributes in superAttributes {
        if (layoutAttributes.representedElementCategory == .Cell) {
            if let indexPath = layoutAttributes.indexPath {
                missingSections.addIndex(layoutAttributes.indexPath.section)
            }
        }
    }

    for layoutAttributes in superAttributes{
        if let representedElementKind = layoutAttributes.representedElementKind {
            if representedElementKind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader {
                if let indexPath = layoutAttributes.indexPath {
                    missingSections.removeIndex(indexPath.section)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    missingSections.enumerateIndexesUsingBlock { idx, stop in
        let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forItem: 0, inSection: idx)
        let layoutAttributes = self.layoutAttributesForSupplementaryViewOfKind(UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, atIndexPath: indexPath)
        superAttributes.addObject(layoutAttributes!)
    }

    for la in superAttributes {

        let layoutAttributes = la as! UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes;

        if let representedElementKind = layoutAttributes.representedElementKind {
            if representedElementKind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader {
                let section = layoutAttributes.indexPath.section
                let numberOfItemsInSection = collectionView!.numberOfItemsInSection(section)

                let firstCellIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forItem: 0, inSection: section)
                let lastCellIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forItem: max(0, (numberOfItemsInSection - 1)), inSection: section)                    

                var firstCellAttributes:UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes
                var lastCellAttributes:UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes

                    if (self.collectionView!.numberOfItemsInSection(section) > 0) {
                            firstCellAttributes = self.layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath(firstCellIndexPath)!
                            lastCellAttributes = self.layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath(lastCellIndexPath)!
                    } else {
                            firstCellAttributes = self.layoutAttributesForSupplementaryViewOfKind(UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, atIndexPath: firstCellIndexPath)!
                            lastCellAttributes = self.layoutAttributesForSupplementaryViewOfKind(UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter, atIndexPath: lastCellIndexPath)!
                    }

                let headerHeight = CGRectGetHeight(layoutAttributes.frame)
                var origin = layoutAttributes.frame.origin

                 origin.y = min(max(contentOffset.y, (CGRectGetMinY(firstCellAttributes.frame) - headerHeight)), (CGRectGetMaxY(lastCellAttributes.frame) - headerHeight))
                ;

                layoutAttributes.zIndex = 1024;
                layoutAttributes.frame = CGRect(origin: origin, size: layoutAttributes.frame.size)

            }
        }
    }

    return NSArray(array: superAttributes) as? [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]
}

override func shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange(newBounds: CGRect) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

Comment: this code is work for vertical scroll only, can you make it works for horizontal scrolling? and the section header on the top?

Answer (score 2):

I fixed my crash by testing for testing for empty sections as suggested in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/toblerpwn/5393460). I also added a couple of `if let`s for extra Swift style points ;-). This now works for me:

```
class StickyHeaderCollectionViewFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

    override func layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect: CGRect) -> [AnyObject]? {

        var answer: [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes] = super.layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect)! as [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]
        let contentOffset = collectionView!.contentOffset

        var missingSections = NSMutableIndexSet()

        for layoutAttributes in answer {
            if (layoutAttributes.representedElementCategory == .Cell) {
                if let indexPath = layoutAttributes.indexPath {
                    missingSections.addIndex(layoutAttributes.indexPath.section)
                }
            }
        }

        for layoutAttributes in answer {
            if let representedElementKind = layoutAttributes.representedElementKind {
                if representedElementKind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader {
                    if let indexPath = layoutAttributes.indexPath {
                        missingSections.removeIndex(indexPath.section)
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        missingSections.enumerateIndexesUsingBlock { idx, stop in
            let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forItem: 0, inSection: idx)
            if let layoutAttributes = self.layoutAttributesForSupplementaryViewOfKind(UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, atIndexPath: indexPath) {
                answer.append(layoutAttributes)
            }
        }

        for layoutAttributes in answer {
            if let representedElementKind = layoutAttributes.representedElementKind {
                if representedElementKind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader {
                    let section = layoutAttributes.indexPath!.section
                    let numberOfItemsInSection = collectionView!.numberOfItemsInSection(section)

                    let firstCellIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forItem: 0, inSection: section)!
                    let lastCellIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forItem: max(0, (numberOfItemsInSection - 1)), inSection: section)!


                    let (firstCellAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes, lastCellAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes) = {
                        if (self.collectionView!.numberOfItemsInSection(section) > 0) {
                            return (
                                self.layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath(firstCellIndexPath),
                                self.layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath(lastCellIndexPath))
                        } else {
                            return (
                                self.layoutAttributesForSupplementaryViewOfKind(UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, atIndexPath: firstCellIndexPath),
                                self.layoutAttributesForSupplementaryViewOfKind(UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter, atIndexPath: lastCellIndexPath))
                        }
                    }()

                    let headerHeight = CGRectGetHeight(layoutAttributes.frame)
                    var origin = layoutAttributes.frame.origin

                    origin.y = min(max(contentOffset.y, (CGRectGetMinY(firstCellAttributes.frame) - headerHeight)), (CGRectGetMaxY(lastCellAttributes.frame) - headerHeight))

                    layoutAttributes.zIndex = 1024
                    layoutAttributes.frame = CGRect(origin: origin, size: layoutAttributes.frame.size)
                }
            }
        }

        return answer
    }

    override func shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange(newBounds: CGRect) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for that! I've updated my answer with your updated part of code.

Comment: Thanks! FYI, in Swift 1.2 the first line of layoutAttributesForElementsIntRect now requires an "as!"

       var answer: [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes] = super.layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect)! as! [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]

Comment: I got a "definition conflicts with previous value" at `let (firstCellAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes, lastCellAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes) = {` in swift 2.0

Answer (score 2):

Cleaner Swift 2.3 tested version of Irina's answer

```
override func layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {

    guard var superAttributes = super.layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect) else {
        return super.layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect)
    }

    let contentOffset = collectionView!.contentOffset
    let missingSections = NSMutableIndexSet()

    for layoutAttributes in superAttributes {
        if (layoutAttributes.representedElementCategory == .Cell) {
            missingSections.addIndex(layoutAttributes.indexPath.section)
        }

        if let representedElementKind = layoutAttributes.representedElementKind {
            if representedElementKind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader {
                missingSections.removeIndex(layoutAttributes.indexPath.section)
            }
        }
    }

    missingSections.enumerateIndexesUsingBlock { idx, stop in
        let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forItem: 0, inSection: idx)
        if let layoutAttributes = self.layoutAttributesForSupplementaryViewOfKind(UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, atIndexPath: indexPath) {
            superAttributes.append(layoutAttributes)
        }
    }

    for layoutAttributes in superAttributes {
        if let representedElementKind = layoutAttributes.representedElementKind {
            if representedElementKind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader {
                let section = layoutAttributes.indexPath.section
                let numberOfItemsInSection = collectionView!.numberOfItemsInSection(section)

                let firstCellIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forItem: 0, inSection: section)
                let lastCellIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forItem: max(0, (numberOfItemsInSection - 1)), inSection: section)

                var firstCellAttributes:UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes
                var lastCellAttributes:UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes

                if (self.collectionView!.numberOfItemsInSection(section) > 0) {
                    firstCellAttributes = self.layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath(firstCellIndexPath)!
                    lastCellAttributes = self.layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath(lastCellIndexPath)!
                } else {
                    firstCellAttributes = self.layoutAttributesForSupplementaryViewOfKind(UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, atIndexPath: firstCellIndexPath)!
                    lastCellAttributes = self.layoutAttributesForSupplementaryViewOfKind(UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter, atIndexPath: lastCellIndexPath)!
                }

                let headerHeight = CGRectGetHeight(layoutAttributes.frame)
                var origin = layoutAttributes.frame.origin

                origin.y = min(max(contentOffset.y, (CGRectGetMinY(firstCellAttributes.frame) - headerHeight)), (CGRectGetMaxY(lastCellAttributes.frame) - headerHeight))
                ;

                layoutAttributes.zIndex = 1024;
                layoutAttributes.frame = CGRect(origin: origin, size: layoutAttributes.frame.size)

            }
        }
    }

    return superAttributes
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Swift 2.2 version tested based on GregP's answer. Greg's code was throwing an unwrap optional error at *lastCellIndexPath* because the number of section is initially zero. So I moved the *numberOfItemsInSection > 0* check up.

```
override func layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {

    let superAttributes:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray(array: super.layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect)!) as NSMutableArray

    let contentOffset = collectionView!.contentOffset
    let missingSections = NSMutableIndexSet()

    for layoutAttributes in superAttributes {
        if (layoutAttributes.representedElementCategory == .Cell) {
            if let _ = layoutAttributes.indexPath {
                missingSections.addIndex(layoutAttributes.indexPath.section)
            }
        }
    }

    for layoutAttributes in superAttributes{
        if let representedElementKind = layoutAttributes.representedElementKind {
            if representedElementKind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader {
                if let indexPath = layoutAttributes.indexPath {
                    missingSections.removeIndex(indexPath.section)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    missingSections.enumerateIndexesUsingBlock { idx, stop in
        let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forItem: 0, inSection: idx)
        let layoutAttributes = self.layoutAttributesForSupplementaryViewOfKind(UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, atIndexPath: indexPath)
        superAttributes.addObject(layoutAttributes!)
    }

    for la in superAttributes {

        let layoutAttributes = la as! UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes;

        if let representedElementKind = layoutAttributes.representedElementKind {
            if representedElementKind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader {
                let section = layoutAttributes.indexPath.section
                let numberOfItemsInSection = collectionView!.numberOfItemsInSection(section)

                if numberOfItemsInSection > 0{
                    let firstCellIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forItem: 0, inSection: section)
                    let lastCellIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forItem: max(0, (numberOfItemsInSection - 1)), inSection: section)

                    var firstCellAttributes:UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes
                    var lastCellAttributes:UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes

                    firstCellAttributes = self.layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath(firstCellIndexPath)!
                    lastCellAttributes = self.layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath(lastCellIndexPath)!

                    let headerHeight = CGRectGetHeight(layoutAttributes.frame)
                    var origin = layoutAttributes.frame.origin

                    origin.y = min(max(contentOffset.y, (CGRectGetMinY(firstCellAttributes.frame) - headerHeight)), (CGRectGetMaxY(lastCellAttributes.frame) - headerHeight));

                    layoutAttributes.zIndex = 1024;
                    layoutAttributes.frame = CGRect(origin: origin, size: layoutAttributes.frame.size)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return NSArray(array: superAttributes) as? [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]
}

override func shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange(newBounds: CGRect) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For people that want to use **sticky header on compositional layout**:

*(change the height value to fit your needs)*

```
let headerKind = UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader
let headerSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1), heightDimension: .absolute(100))
    
let headerElement = NSCollectionLayoutBoundarySupplementaryItem(layoutSize: headerSize, elementKind: headerKind, alignment: .top)
// for sticky header
headerElement.pinToVisibleBounds = true
    
section.boundarySupplementaryItems = [headerElement]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution that works if you only have one section.

```
class StickyHeaderLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

  override func shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange(newBounds: CGRect) -> Bool {
    return true
  }

  override func layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect: CGRect) -> [AnyObject]? {
    var attributes = super.layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect)! as! [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]

      let offset          = collectionView?.contentOffset


      for attrs in attributes {
        if attrs.representedElementKind == nil {
          let indexPath        = NSIndexPath(forItem: 0, inSection: attrs.indexPath.section)
          let layoutAttributes = self.layoutAttributesForSupplementaryViewOfKind(UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, atIndexPath: indexPath)

          attributes.append(layoutAttributes)
        }
      }

      for attrs in attributes {
        if attrs.representedElementKind == nil {
          continue
        }

        if attrs.representedElementKind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader {

          var headerRect = attrs.frame
          headerRect.size.height = headerHeight
          headerRect.origin.y = offset!.y
          attrs.frame = headerRect
          attrs.zIndex = 1024
          break
        }
      }

    return attributes
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3 version trying to avoid !'s where it made sense.

```
class StickyHeaderCollectionViewFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

    override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
        guard var superAttributes = super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect), let collectionView = collectionView else {
            return super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect)
        }

        let collectionViewTopY = collectionView.contentOffset.y + collectionView.contentInset.top
        let contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: collectionViewTopY)
        let missingSections = NSMutableIndexSet()

        superAttributes.forEach { layoutAttributes in
            if layoutAttributes.representedElementCategory == .cell && layoutAttributes.representedElementKind != UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader {
                missingSections.add(layoutAttributes.indexPath.section)
            }
        }

        missingSections.enumerate(using: { idx, stop in
            let indexPath = IndexPath(item: 0, section: idx)
            if let layoutAttributes = self.layoutAttributesForSupplementaryView(ofKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, at: indexPath) {
                superAttributes.append(layoutAttributes)
            }
        })

        for layoutAttributes in superAttributes {
            if let representedElementKind = layoutAttributes.representedElementKind {
                if representedElementKind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader {
                    let section = layoutAttributes.indexPath.section
                    let numberOfItemsInSection = collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: section)

                    let firstCellIndexPath = IndexPath(item: 0, section: section)
                    let lastCellIndexPath = IndexPath(item: max(0, (numberOfItemsInSection - 1)), section: section)                   

                    let cellAttributes:(first: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes, last: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes) = {
                        if (collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: section) > 0) {
                            return (
                                self.layoutAttributesForItem(at: firstCellIndexPath)!,
                                self.layoutAttributesForItem(at: lastCellIndexPath)!)
                        } else {
                            return (
                                self.layoutAttributesForSupplementaryView(ofKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, at: firstCellIndexPath)!,
                                self.layoutAttributesForSupplementaryView(ofKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter, at: lastCellIndexPath)!)
                        }
                    }()

                    let headerHeight = layoutAttributes.frame.height
                    var origin = layoutAttributes.frame.origin
                    // This line makes only one header visible fixed at the top
//                    origin.y = min(contentOffset.y, cellAttributes.last.frame.maxY - headerHeight)
                    // Uncomment this line for normal behaviour:
                    origin.y = min(max(contentOffset.y, cellAttributes.first.frame.minY - headerHeight), cellAttributes.last.frame.maxY - headerHeight)

                    layoutAttributes.zIndex = 1024
                    layoutAttributes.frame = CGRect(origin: origin, size: layoutAttributes.frame.size)
                }
            }
        }

        return superAttributes
    }

    override func shouldInvalidateLayout(forBoundsChange newBounds: CGRect) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

i use this in my project. Hope it helps.

```
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
    referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize
{
    return CGSizeMake(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, 40)
}
```

of course. you can return whatever size you want.