# Swift - Make the first row of UICollectionView a sticky header

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, sticky

I have a large list of data in my Collection View, the number of rows and columns are dynamic, they change when I push a button to filter.

I've created my Collection View programatically, all the data become from my server **and even the titles of the header**.

My server can return, for example:
Code   |  Name      |  Phone          | Address                               | Others columns until the end ...

2         
|  Eevee    
| 876321342 
| In a big commercial center  | 
10       
|  Mewtwo 
| 673812332 
| In a cave                              | 
...
...

Well, my problem is, I don't know how to create a header programatically, so I think **is possible convert my first row of my Collection View as a header row and make it sticky**, or, another way to make it fixed, taking into account whenever I have to scroll horizontal and vertical of course.

Is there any way to do that?

PS: My app is not about pokemon, so do not try to call Mewtwo please (:

Comment: Take a look here: https://cocoacasts.com/how-to-add-sticky-section-headers-to-a-collection-view/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UICollectionView sticky header in swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27316263/uicollectionview-sticky-header-in-swift)

Comment: @AhmadF No, I already tried it days ago, from that link. That way doesn't work when I refresh all the data (included headers) which I returned from server and rewrite it in my CollectionView. I put the two lines after .reloadData() when press the button and didn't work.