# Sticky UICollectionView Header F#

Tags: ios, f#, xamarin.ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a `UICollectionViewController` with the following layout:

[image]

So we have a CollectionView and a Header containing a Reusable View.

I implement the following method for the reusable view:

```
override x.GetViewForSupplementaryElement(collectionView : UICollectionView, elementKind : NSString, indexPath : NSIndexPath) =
    let headerView = (collectionView.DequeueReusableSupplementaryView(elementKind,new NSString("HeaderView"),indexPath))
    headerView
```

My only problem is, I do not want the header to scroll along with the `UICollectionView`, I want it to stay in a fixed position at all times on top of the `UICollectionView`. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using the following code:

```
let layout = x.CollectionView.CollectionViewLayout :?> UICollectionViewFlowLayout
layout.SectionHeadersPinToVisibleBounds <- true
```

Adapted from [UICollectionView sticky header in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27316263/uicollectionview-sticky-header-in-swift?rq=1)

In order to eliminate white space on top of collectionView do the following:

```
x.AutomaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets <- false
x.CollectionView.ContentInset <- UIEdgeInsets(Conversions.nfloat(-44),Conversions.nfloat(0), Conversions.nfloat(0), Conversions.nfloat(0))
```

Note that the value of `-44` is used for iPhone X specifically, and might differ for other models.

Conversions is used to convert to `nfloat`. This is the code that does this conversion:

```
let inline nfloat (x:^a) : ^b = ((^a or ^b) : (static member op_Implicit : ^a -> nfloat) x)
```

Finally, if you wish to eliminate vertical bouncing on top of the `UICollectionView` add the following code to your `UICollectionViewController` :

```
override x.Scrolled(scrollView : UIScrollView) = 
    if (scrollView.ContentOffset.Y < Conversions.nfloat(0)) then 
        scrollView.ContentOffset <- CGPoint(scrollView.ContentOffset.X, Conversions.nfloat(0))
```

Comment: Asked and answered.  

Comment: The only problem I have now is that there is a white space above the header where the status bar is, and when I scroll up the cells show up on top of the status bar