# collectionViewCell disable scrolling

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a collectionView with multiple cells. I was wondering if it is possible to stop the top section(section 0) from scrolling while allowing the rest of the sections to continue to scroll. All of the answers I have seen talks about enabling or disabling the entire collection view to scroll. In my case I want the collectionView to scroll, except I want section 0 to not scroll at all. Is this possible or do I have to have two separate collectionViews?

```
 override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
    var reusableview = UICollectionReusableView()
    if (kind == UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader) {
        let section = indexPath.section
        switch (section) {
        case 0:

            let headerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: headerIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? Header
           
        case 1:
            let Section1 = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: Section1, for: indexPath) as? Section
            
        case 2:
            let Section2 = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: Section2, for: indexPath) as? Section2
            
        case 3:
            let Section3 = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: Section3, for: indexPath) as? Section3
        
         case 4:
                  let Section4 = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: Section4, for: indexPath) as? Section4
                default:
            return reusableview

        }
    }
    
    return reusableview
    
}
```

Comment: so you want section 0 to be pinned to the beginning and the rest to be scrollable?

Comment: @OmerTekbiyik correct

Comment: You need to add as a header and make some setting to collectionview's layout. Following answers https://stackoverflow.com/q/27316263/9110909 .

Comment: @OmerTekbiyik After looking over I think mine is a little tricky and wanted to get your opinion. Essentially, I have 5 headers. Section 0-4. These all represent different things. Would I have to establish section 0 as the header and 1-4 as sections of the header? I have updated my question to show code.

Comment: @OmerTekbiyik were you able to take a look?

Comment: yes you need to add headers to all sections

Comment: @OmerTekbiyik isn't that what I am doing?